# Outlook Rest API returning no results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to display a list of events from an Outlook calendar using the example request [microsoft have here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations)

However, I've no proper experience with using any sort of REST APIs before. Using the URL they provide I should be getting something back but I'm not. Here is the code in my controller:

```
  string uri = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events";

    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        result = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
        try
        {
            string returnedString = result;
            TempData.Add("myval", result);
            ViewBag.result = "returned string " + result;

        }
        catch (Exception er2)
        {
            ViewBag.error = er2.Message;
        }

        ViewBag.secondresult = "first result " + result;
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {


    }

    ViewBag.firstResult = "Outside try catch " + result;
    ViewBag.url = uri;
    return View();
```

Then in my view I'm calling the `ViewBags` like this:

```
<p> here </p>
@ViewBag.url
@ViewBag.firstResult                        
@ViewBag.result
@ViewBag.error
@ViewBag.secondresult
<p> end </p>
```

But besides my `here` and `end` I get nothing. This is a project that was set up without any input from myself so I'm having to do everything across a network which is why I'm using so many `try catches`.

Can someone with more experience with using REST APIs tell me if I'm messing something up somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any authentication in your code, so it's likely returning a 401. You need to use OAuth2 to get an access token and use that to authenticate your calls. Since you're doing this in C#, you might want to look at the API wrappers on NuGet that implement a lot of this for you. There are some sample starter apps on http://dev.office.com/code-samples that might be helpful too (search for ASP.NET MVC).